# Load an array with react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a problem with the react.js code below, the services performs the loading of an array of values ​​what interests me at this moment is the first value of the array inside the component, if I display the first CodArt value before configuring the setState (so if I view the console.log) the value is printed when I view it through the setState tells me that it is not set.

**Services.js :**

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

export async function caricamentoarticoliutilizzati() {
    var listaarticoli=[];
    await axios.post(server.url+'/articolo/statistiche', {})
      .then(function (response) {
        let data = response.data;
        for (let index in data){
          var datatemp={
            CodMarca : data[index].CodMarca,
            CodArt : data[index].CodArt,
            Totale : data[index].Totale
          };
          listaarticoli.push(datatemp);
        }
        }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Errore: "+error);
      });
      return listaarticoli;
}
```

**Main.js:**

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      graph: null,
      checkedArr: [false, false, false],
      totalePreventiviInseriti: 0,
      percentualeAccettati:0,
      percentualeRifutati:0,
      percentualeInCorso:0,
      percentualeCantieriChiusi:0,
      percentualeCantieriInCorso:0,
      percentualeCantieriContoInviato:0,
      percentualeCantieriBolle:0,
      articoliUtilizzati:[],
    };
    this.checkTable = this.checkTable.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {


  var totalePreventiviInseriti= await getStatistichePreventivi();
  var percentualeAccettati=await getStatistichePreventiviAccettati();
  var percentualeRifutati=await getStatistichePreventiviRifiutati();
  var percentualeInCorso=await getStatistichePreventiviInCorso();
  var cantieriPercentualiChiusi=await getStatisticheCantieri("Chiuso");
  var cantieriPercentualiInCorso=await getStatisticheCantieri("InCorso");
  var percentualeCantieriContoInviato=await getStatisticheCantieri("Conto Inviato");
  var percentualeCantieriBolle=await getStatisticheCantieri("Lavoro terminato inserire bolle ");
  var articoliUtilizzati=await caricamentoarticoliutilizzati();
  console.log("articoliUtilizzati: "+ articoliUtilizzati[0].CodArt.toString());
  //Inserimento valori nello stato
  this.setState({ totalePreventiviInseriti: totalePreventiviInseriti });
  this.setState({ percentualeAccettati: percentualeAccettati });
  this.setState({ percentualeRifutati: percentualeRifutati });
  this.setState({percentualeInCorso: percentualeInCorso});
  this.setState({percentualeCantieriChiusi: cantieriPercentualiChiusi});
  this.setState({percentualeCantieriInCorso: cantieriPercentualiInCorso});
  this.setState({percentualeCantieriContoInviato: percentualeCantieriContoInviato});
  this.setState({percentualeCantieriBolle: percentualeCantieriBolle});
  this.setState({articoliUtilizzati: articoliUtilizzati});
  }

  render(){


   ....


   <p> this.state.articoliUtilizzati[0].CodArt //-->CodArt not set
  }
```

Comment: What's the value you're getting inside the p tag ? Or the exact error ?

Comment: Shouldn't you wrap `this.state.articoliUtilizzati[0].CodArt`  in curlybraces in `render()`?

Answer (score 0):

that is because the call to `caricamentoarticoliutilizzati` return a promise not the array `listaarticoli`. so in `componenetDidMount` the variable  `articoliUtilizzati` holds a promise object you can confirm this by:

```
var articoliUtilizzati=await caricamentoarticoliutilizzati();
console.log("articoliUtilizzati: "+ articoliUtilizzati.then(arr =>arr[0].CodArt.toString()));
```

Comment: no on first console.log value has print, but in this.state.articoliUtilizzati the value not print

Comment: that is expected because `render` is called before `componentDidMount`, by the time `render` is called the state variable `articoliUtilizzati` is still empty array.